# ASP.NET MVC Controller Action Executing 4 Times Per Request

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, firebug

Has anyone come across something like this before? Basically, I have an action on a controller that merely queries the database via a repository pattern, adds some data to the ViewData then returns the View. But for some reason this action is being called **4 times per request**.

The whole action itself is only about 10 lines long:

```
public ActionResult Details(int id, string slug) {
    Product p = productRepository.GetProduct(id);

    IEnumerable<Image> imgs = productRepository.GetImages(p.ProductId);
    if (imgs.Count() > 0) {
        ViewData["MainImage"] = imgs.First();
        ViewData["Images"] = imgs;
    }

    Brand brand = productRepository.GetBrand(p.ProductId);
    ViewData["Brand"] = brand;

    var categories = productRepository.GetCategories(p.ProductId, true);
    ViewData["ProductCategories"] = categories;

    return View("Details", p);
}
```

Also, the routes defined in my Global.asax are as follows:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "SlugsAfterId",
    "{controller}.mvc/{action}/{id}/{slug}",
    new { controller = "Products", action = "Browse", id = "" }
);

// The default route that comes with ASP.NET MVC
routes.MapRoute(
    "Default",                                              // Route name
    "{controller}.mvc/{action}/{id}",                           // URL with parameters
    new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = "" }  // Parameter defaults
);
```

Can anyone shed any light on this please? I am completely stumped.

Comment: How do you know this is happening 4 times?

Comment: It is listed 4 times in the Firebug Net -> HTML panel. I double-checked this myself using Burp Suite and it is indeed requesting the page 4 times.

Comment: Uhh, that might be another issue not related to MVC.  Are you sure the 4 requests aren't just for CSS/JS files?  Sounds like this might be some async requests or something.  Are each one of the requests HTTP 200?  They might be HTTP 30x redirects.

Comment: Can you post your client side code? If you are seeing it in Firebug then the requests are coming from the client-side and have nothing to do with MVC or your server side code.

Comment: Yes, they're all HTTP 200. I tried it with CSS and JavaScript disabled and I still got the 4 requests. I just tried it with images disabled and there was only 1 request. @Chad Moran - can you put your last comment as an answer so I can mark it as *the answer*?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Looks like those requests might be client-side requests like images, css or js files.

Comment: Thanks - it was all down to some images with missing src attributes.

Comment: Yeah sure, I've had this happen to me before too. : )